# Override whole class in java/scala

Tags: java, scala, inheritance

I have a library, already provided, which has two Scala classes:

```
class EvaluationFunction (data:DataHolder) {
    def calculate(params:ParamHolder) = {...}
}
```

And

```
class Regression {
    def train(data:DataHolder) = {
        ...
        val costFunction = new EvaluationFunction(data)

        //find params to minimize costFunction.calculate(params)
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to make my own regression class, which behaves exactly like the original regression, but uses a different evaluation function. However, the only way I can think of to do that would involve extending Regression and overwriting the whole train method. But it contains pretty much all the logic in the Regression class - I may as well write it from scratch!

Is there a better way? For example, somehow tell my extended regression class to invoke another class every time the original invokes EvaluationFunction?

Comment: Do you control the Regression class? Then just encapsulate the parts you wish to adjust in a method and override that

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't :(

Answer (score 3):

The code you show would not compile: the `data` does not have a datatype.

That aside - the structure of the `Regression` class is strange. It should have the `EvaluationFunction` as overridable. As it stands it is built into the `train` method. That is why you need to override (/rewrite) the entire class. It is a problem with the class structure.

Comment: I though the data type isn't really relevant, and skipped it. Anyway, the problem is, I don't have any control over the Regression class.

Comment: The problem remains the same - the `Regression` class is mal-constructed. Go have a little chat with the library maintainers. Or .. rewrite the whole thing.